# How do I check my result in GNUSim8085?

Tags: assembly

I have written some simple and working assembly code on 8085 trainer hardware.
But I am unable to check my result for my first program, on **GNUSim8085**.
I just load 2 numbers, add them and store the result in memory.
Take a look at code, registers and memory below (after successful execution of program)
[image]
Before executing code I had put '11' in location 1000 and '78' in location 1001.
so after execution location 1002 should have '89', but it is 0(as visible in image)
Also when i tried stepping through, registers A and B never changed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memory address you are reading and modifying is in decimal. Whereas in your code you entered address as `1000h` and `1001h`.

Either convert 1000 to hexadecimal i.e `03E8h` or change your code i.e. `1000` (drop h).
Or change the locations where you are writing the numbers to be added.